# Any db connection with Factory Pattern, need clarification and review of my method

Tags: c#, database, factory-pattern

I have this project where I try to implement a methodology so i can connect to any database. Following this site (and google), the best practice to achieve that is with a factory pattern (I've seen a few people referring to an abstract factory pattern but i never used it so i stayed with a factory pattern). So I've approached this problem with a factory pattern and created a interface for my Connection which looks like this:

```
interface IConnection
{
    string ConnectionString { get; set;}
    IDbConnection CreateConnection { get; }
}
```

I'm using `IDbConnection` since the main db providers seems to implement it.

I'm not sure if I need anything else there.

After this I created my Factory class which look like this:

```
class clsFactoryDB
{
    static public IConnection CreateDBConnection(int cChoice)
    {
        IConnection ObjSelector = null;
        switch (cChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                ObjSelector = new clsSQL();
                break;
            default:
                ObjSelector = new clsSQL();
                break;
        }
        return ObjSelector;

    }
}
```

For now I just defined SQL but MySQL or Oracle follow the same procedure so I don't bother I'll add it later.

And finally I created my `IConnection` implementation like that:

```
class clsSQL : IConnection
{
    private DbConnection connection;

    string IConnection.ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    IDbConnection IConnection.CreateConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerConnection"].ConnectionString);
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my app.config I've added a property for all the connection strings which I'm referring with `ConfigurationManager`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="SqlServerConnection" connectionString="SQL..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name ="MySqlServerConnection" connectionString="MySQL..." providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    //add more
  </connectionStrings>
```

So my first question is: Is my implementation of this concept right or am i missing something? Again to make this I only followed some topics already posted here, I've also read  bit on code project but their stuff is always confusing.

Now my confusion comes from the fact that to make this work the connection string and provider has to be declared in app.config file (or web.config for asp). But I'm not always connecting to the same server, so I need to change the connection string (that's why i have added a `ConnectionString` method in my `IConnection` interface). Am I right? Therefore if I understand this correctly, I now can manipulate any db with ONE object just by changing the connection string as needed to connect to different databases.

Please correct any mistakes I could have made here. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/implementation-of-abstract-factory-pattern-with-adonet1

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/abstract-factory-design-pattern-in-ado-net-2-0/

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ok i'll try posting it there, i only have acces to stackoverflow at work and most of the stuff i found come from here.

Comment: I would look into using a DI container to specify named instances to register each database type, then you could use an app setting to select the code path (and therefore database type to use) at run-time without polluting your code with a switch statement that will grow and grow as more database types are added. The app setting could be read and used to specify the named instance to use which would keep your code much cleaner.

If you're keen to keep things as they are, make cChoice an enum, it'll make the code easier to manage by putting a name to the choice rather than a random int.

Comment: @Marc Thank you, I'll look more into DI Container and how I can implement it. If i can get rid of that switch that would be a nice solution for a cleaner code thanks :-)

Comment: It's a minor detail, but I would use an enum for the different types of connections (which you can then also use as the key name in your config file) It reduces the need to use magic strings that can easily contain a typo. `public enum DbType { SqlServer, MySql, AnotherDb }`

Comment: @Flater yeah i did that. I still don't understand the point of this tho. Is it really only so you can have one object for any db? Cause the connection string has to be changed if you connect to different db so the use of app.config is useless actually.

Comment: @user5014677: It's a matter of preventing typo's by using Intellisense. There's no benefit other than lowering the odds of a developer making a mistake.

Comment: @Flater I did'nt mean the Enum.

Comment: @user5014677 Did you mean to respond to Marc then? Because I only talked about the enum...

Comment: @Flater Nah, i just asked about the whole Factory any db method. A lot of people do this but i don't see the purpose of this.

Comment: @user5014677: The purpose of a factory is to make sure that the creation of database objects happens in one place (as opposed to having it everywhere in your codebase); and also to make it possible for you to change your internal logic (which database object class you choose to return) without affecting everyone who calls on that method.