# Is there a way to select a default Driver for a connection string?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I've made a factory pattern that returns an object to manipulate any type of database (well so far i only have OleDB,ODBC and sql). I've posted my implementation here: Any db connection with Factory Pattern, need clarification and review of my method But i would like to know if there's any method to get a default driver per type of connection. Like for example I'm currently doing something like this:

```
    factory = new FactoryDB();
    connection = factory.CreateDBConnection(FactoryDbType.Odbc);

    connection.Driver = "{InterSystems ODBC}";
    connection.ServerIP = secretObject.IP;
    connection.Port = secretObject.Port.ToString();
    connection.DataBase = secretObject.DBName;
    connection.UID = secretObject.UserName;
    connection.Password = "password";
```

And then i just have a method inside my factory that creates the connection string based on those information. I can also set the connection string directly without having to set up all the properties like this: `connection.ConnectionString = "Driver={InterSystems ODBC};Server=someIP;DataBase=SomeDB;UID=somUID;PWD=somePassword;PORT=somePort"`;

All the parameters have to be obviously written by the developer (or user if it's oriented that way).

And i wonder if i could bypass the need to specify a driver and select the default Odbc/OleDB/Sql/... driver installed on the machine or is it something we have to specify everytime?

Comment: This is besides the point, but is there a specific reason not to use [DbProviderFactories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.aspx) to get a [DbProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx) to create connections (and commands, parameters, etc.)? -- Btw. you can use [DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.getfactoryclasses.aspx) to get all installed providers. -- Don't know if there is a "default" one, though.

Comment: @Corak I searched for a way to create a db connection to any database literally no one has ever mentioned that this exists... Amazing, I still have a problem with this tho i'll make another question for it.

Comment: Well, to be fair, the URL in the first comment of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44283370/1336590) has an example that uses `DbProviderFactories`/`DbProviderFactory`. -- still, you need to build the connection string specific to the providers somehow. A good reference for that is [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).